# How to use the lastb command from Mac terminal?

Tags: linux, mac, bash, terminal

In bash on mac, when trying to list recent bad logins, the `lastb` command is unrecognized, while it works fine on my Linux machine. Does it need to be installed or is it a different command for macs?

Answer (score 0):

While there is BSD `last` for OS X which just shows successful logins, I do not know if there is a command that lists recent bad logins. You could use `grep` to display such information, like:
`$ grep -E 'LOGIN FAILURE | authentication error for | BAD SU | incorrect password attempts' /var/log/system.log`

"LOGIN FAILURE" = failed local logins
"authentication error for" = failed SSH logins
"BAD SU" = wrong password inputted when using `su`
"incorrect password attempts" = wrong password inputted when using `sudo`

Edit: [util-linux](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux) features GNU/Linux `last` + `lastb` but I am not sure if it will run on Darwin (OS X)